# Вызов JS функции, которая должна быть в коде ниже

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день.
Код:

```
<script src="" onerror="func()"></script>
```

Но действия, которые должны быть выполнены этой функцией, должны находиться в коде ниже, там идет замена блоков:

```
function func() {   
$('.blok1').show();
$('.blok2').hide();
}
```

И т.д.
Соотв. если я пишу эту функцию ниже onerror, то функция не определена, если выше, то не происходит замена блоков.

Работает если выше onerror написать:

```
function func() {   
$(function () {
$('.blok1').show();
$('.blok2').hide();
}); 
}
```

Но меня смущает такая конструкция, наверняка можно же как то сделать умнее :)

Comment: вынесите скрипты в отдельный файл хоть

Comment: Зачем?
Мне вообще то не нужно в файлы выносить, мне в 1 страницу все надо встроить.

Comment: Ну количество страниц от этого не вырастет :))

Comment: вообще вся идея выглядит странно, вы уверены что этому скрипту нужно срабатывать при ошибке загрузки скрипта?))

Comment: Вообще задумка такая, что грузится удаленный скрипт, например с картой.
Если он не загрузился, я прячу блок, с этой картой и показываю альтернативный блок, который при удачной загрузке удаленного скрипта скрыт.